# Learning OSX terminal in depth - How to solve the "usr/bin/python: No module named..." error

Tags: python-3.x, zsh, virtualenvwrapper

I'm learning my way around console again and would love to understand error messages in depth. Using Mac OSX and ZSH.

**Here is the first one to crack:**

```
Last login: Thu Mar 29 16:00:27 on ttys000
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

This obviously means that one of the Pythons installed on my Mac could not load one of the packages (virtualenvwrapper). To orient myself I tried a couple of things to get the "stats" about my system.

**Here is what I tried:**

```
~ ❯ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

*First Python (system one, the one that comes with Apple OSX)*

```
~ ❯ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

*Second Python (Python3, installed by me via Homebrew package manager)*

```
~ ❯ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

~ ❯ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

*Same as with pythons, two PIPs - first one is the one that "works with" the system Python installation, and the second one that comes with brewed Python3.*

```
~ ❯ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin
```

seems that my $PATH variable is set properly in the `~/.zshrc` (is this the proper file?)

**Potential culprit:**

```
~ ❯ pip install virtualenvwrapper                                                                
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

~ ❯ pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Is this the problem? Both PIPs are saying that I already have the missing package installed, but in the same location (in the brewed Python3). Do I need to re-link something?

**EDIT:**

I tried one more thing:

```
printenv | less
```

returns this:

```
WORKON_HOME=/users/edchigliak/documents/projects/.virtualenvs
PROJECT_HOME=/users/edchigliak/documents/projects
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME=.project
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD=1
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR=/users/edchigliak/documents/projects/.virtualenvs
```

Last line might be the suspect. Seems that the ZSH cannot source thie "... _HOOK_DIR" I just don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You have two different Python installations, and they know nothing about each other. You have to tell the system Python installation about the second installation with [the Python module paths](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). And make sure that both the system and use installation are the same version of Python!

Comment: try `/usr/local/bin/pip install virtualenvwrapper` there might be a pip-symlink to pip3 (just guessing)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks for the reply! ;) I don't want to have two same versions, the point was to leave the system one as is, and try the Python3 for programming. I am not sure how to use module paths to rectify this problem (Python newbie here). Can I just "turn off" system python and make the OS not complain any more?

Comment: I don't know about macOS, but on many other systems the `python` program is just a link. On my Debian Linux system (for example) `/usr/bin/python` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/python2.7`. If it's similar on macOS then maybe there might be a way to change this link? So your `/usr/bin/python` is a link to `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue - I added the following line to my shell configuration file (in my case `~/.zshrc`):

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

By doing so I obviously told virtualenvwrapper where to look for "proper" python (python 3 instead of the system-wide installed python 2).